# Dart group list of items into a different data structure?

Tags: list, algorithm, dart, grouping

I have these classes:

```
class Car {
  String carId;
  int yearOfManufacture;
  //constructor, fromJson, toJson ...
}

class CarsByYears {
  int yearOfManufacture;
  List<Car> carList;
  //constructor, fromJson, toJson ...
}
```

And I need to generate a data structure like this based on the given car list only:

```
List<CarsByYears>
```

So I get a `List<Car>` list, and I need to create a `List<CarsByYears>` list from that. So I need to group the cars by years.
For example I have a `List<Car>` list which contains these:

```
Car(1, 1990)
Car(2, 2001)
Car(3, 1990)
```

I need to create a `List<CarsByYears>`, which contains 2 `CarsByYears` object:

The first one is like: `yearOfManufacture = 1990` and the `carList` contains the 1st and the 3rd car object, and the other `CarsByYears` is contains the 2nd Car object in its carList, and the `yearOfManufacture = 2001`

How can I do that?

Comment: Tip: create a Map<int, CarsByYears> indexed by the year, or better, use Map<int, List<Car>>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `groupBy` function provided by the [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package (which creates a map from a List groping it using a common value as key) and then map the `Map` entries.

```
class Car {
  final String carId;
  final int yearOfManufacture;

  Car(this.carId, this.yearOfManufacture);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Car($carId)';

  // Use your constructor and methods
}

class CarsByYears {
  final int yearOfManufacture;
  final List<Car> carList;

  CarsByYears(this.yearOfManufacture, this.carList);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Year: $yearOfManufacture, Cars: $carList';

  // Use your constructor and methods
}

void main() {
  var cars = [
    Car('1', 2000),
    Car('2', 2002),
    Car('3', 2000),
    Car('4', 2002),
    Car('1', 2005)
  ];
  var carsByYear = groupBy<Car, int>(cars, (e) => e.yearOfManufacture)
      .entries
      .map((e) => CarsByYears(e.key, e.value))
      .toList();
  print(carsByYear); //Output: [Year: 2000, Cars: [Car(1), Car(3)], Year: 2002, Cars: [Car(2), Car(4)], Year: 2005, Cars: [Car(1)]]

}
```